# \printbibliography is not working. How can I make it work at emacs with AUCTEX?

Tags: biblatex, emacs, auctex

Using overleaf actually works, but when using emacs, the \printbibliography prints nothing.
I'm also using C-c C-c and Latex, C-c C-c Biber and C-c C-c Latex again, and it does nothing.

My document is exactly as follows:

```
\documentclass[12, arial, stu, floatsintext]{apa7}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\shorttitle{ }
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referencias.bib}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}[=v4.13]
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{sectsty}

%\sectionfont{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont}


\begin{document}
\title{Problemas locales y globales mediante el abordaje de la gestión ambiental}
\author{Jesús Armando Peña Lucero  \\ Matrícula: ES202104991}
\affiliation{Universidad Abierta y a Distancia de México}
\course{Asignatura: Gestión ambiental}
\professor{Docente: Carlos Mauricio Calderilla Jaime}
\duedate{22-Marzo-2022}



\maketitle
\section{Introducción}
\section{Desarrollo}
\subsection{¿Qué es la gestión ambiental}
Son actividades orientadas a mitigar y/o prevenir problemas ambientales.
Responde a las acciones ncesarias para conseguir equilibrio entre desarrollo económico, crecimiento poblacional y uso racionald e recursos para permitir la protección y conservación del ambiente. \cite{UnADM}(UnADM., S.F.)

\subsection{Tipos de instrumentos de la gestión ambiental}

\begin{longtable}{>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.45\linewidth}>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.45\linewidth}}
\hline
\textbf{Instrumento} & \textbf{Tipo de instrumento} \\ \hline
\endhead{}
%
Auditorías ambientales & Respuesta\\ \hline
Investigación y educación ambiental & Respuesta\\ \hline
Análisis de ciclo de vida & Respuesta\\ \hline
Programa de manejo integral de las emisiones, agua, residuos, etc. & Respuesta\\ \hline
Etiquetado ecológico & Respuesta\\ \hline
Ordenamiento ecológico del territorio & Respuesta\\ \hline

\end{longtable}

\subsection{¿Cómo están formados los sistemas ecológicos?}
\subsection{¿Cuáles son las ciencias que se relacionan con la gestión ambiental?}

\begin{longtable}{>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.45\linewidth}>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.45\linewidth}}
\hline
\textbf{Ámbito} & \textbf{Problemáticas} \\ \hline
\endhead{}
%
Agua & 3 Respuestas (tambien para las de abajo)\\ \hline
Suelo & Respuesta\\ \hline
Flora & Respuesta\\ \hline
Fauna & Respuesta\\ \hline
Ecosistemas & Respuesta\\ \hline

\end{longtable}

\subsection[1]{¿Cómo aborda la gestión ambiental las problemáticas?}

\subsection[1]{Problemáticas en mi lugar de origen}

\subsection{¿Qué es un sistema de gestión ambiental?}

\subsection{¿Qué es un diagnóstico ambiental?}



\printbibliography[]

\end{document}
```

My .bib document looks like this:

```
@Book{UnADM,
  author          = {UnADM},
  title           = {Programa de la asignatura: Gestión ambiental U1},
  date            = {s.f.}}
```

Comment: Your code works for me, although biber complains about the `date` format being wrong (which it appears to be). The problem probably has to do with the way you have emacs/AUCTEX configured, but I don't know much about that. Can you run the commands from the command line?

Comment: which commands?

Comment: Cross-post at https://old.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/u3kgki/kinda_noob_here_how_can_i_make_biblatex_work_on/

Comment: `pdflatex "filename.tex"` then `biber "filename.bcf"` then `pdflatex "filename.tex"` (twice) (or `xelatex` in place of `pdflatex` if you're using that instead...) (I'm assuming you're using a linux/unix environment, but you might not be.)

Comment: I'm using linux, indeed. 
I followed your steps, and I saw that I did not have biber installed. 
I'm not sure what worked, but I installed biber from the terminal (which I though it was installed with auctex). Leaving the date field empty instead of using "no-date" or something like that on the bib file also works.

Thank you so much for your help, @frabjous !